# MongoDB: How to deal with invalid ObjectIDs

Tags: json, scala, playframework, reactivemongo

Here below is my code to find a document by ObjectID:

```
def find(selector: JsValue, projection: Option[JsValue], sort: Option[JsValue],
  page: Int, perPage: Int): Future[Seq[JsValue]] = {

  var query = collection.genericQueryBuilder.query(selector).options(
    QueryOpts(skipN = page * perPage)
  )

  projection.map(value => query = query.projection(value))
  sort.map(value => query = query.sort(value.as[JsObject]))

  // this is the line where the call crashes
  query.cursor[JsValue].collect[Vector](perPage).transform(
    success => success,
    failure => failure match {
      case e: LastError => DaoException(e.message, Some(DATABASE_ERROR))
    }
  )
}
```

Now let's suppose we invoke this method with an invalid ObjectID:

```
// ObjectId 53125e9c2004006d04b605abK is invalid (ends with a K)
find(Json.obj("_id" -> Json.obj("$oid" -> "53125e9c2004006d04b605abK")), None, None, 0, 25)
```

The call above causes the following exception when executing `query.cursor[JsValue].collect[Vector](perPage)` in the `find` method:

```
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: JsError.get
        at play.api.libs.json.JsError.get(JsResult.scala:11) ~[play-json_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
        at play.api.libs.json.JsError.get(JsResult.scala:10) ~[play-json_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
        at play.modules.reactivemongo.json.collection.JSONGenericHandlers$StructureBufferWriter$.write(jsoncollection.scala:44) ~[play2-reactivemongo_2.10-0.10.2.jar:0.10.2]
        at play.modules.reactivemongo.json.collection.JSONGenericHandlers$StructureBufferWriter$.write(jsoncollection.scala:42) ~[play2-reactivemongo_2.10-0.10.2.jar:0.10.2]
        at reactivemongo.api.collections.GenericQueryBuilder$class.reactivemongo$api$collections$GenericQueryBuilder$$write(genericcollection.scala:323) ~[reactivemongo_2.10-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
        at reactivemongo.api.collections.GenericQueryBuilder$class.cursor(genericcollection.scala:342) ~[reactivemongo_2.10-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
        at play.modules.reactivemongo.json.collection.JSONQueryBuilder.cursor(jsoncollection.scala:110) ~[play2-reactivemongo_2.10-0.10.2.jar:0.10.2]
        at reactivemongo.api.collections.GenericQueryBuilder$class.cursor(genericcollection.scala:331) ~[reactivemongo_2.10-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
        at play.modules.reactivemongo.json.collection.JSONQueryBuilder.cursor(jsoncollection.scala:110) ~[play2-reactivemongo_2.10-0.10.2.jar:0.10.2]
        at services.common.mongo.MongoDaoComponent$MongoDao$$anon$1.find(MongoDaoComponent.scala:249) ~[classes/:na]
        ... 25 common frames omitted
```

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the whole stack trace please?  There might be more information that can help.

Comment: I've just updated my post with the stack trace I've found in the application log. Anyway, I managed to handle this exception and return the proper error message in the JSON response.

Comment: That seems like a weird Exception to throw in the case of invalid input though - is that normal?  Might it be better to try converting "53125e9c2004006d04b605abK" into an ObjectId before passing it in to the find() method so you can make sure you're dealing with the correct error case?

Comment: Selector contains valid JSON (not BSON) like {"_id": { "$oid": "53125e9c2004006d04b605abK"}}... then is query.cursor that fails.